# Appending show/edit/destroy links to table in rails - Using coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, html-table

I've created a modal that allows a user to create a new record (In this case, an 'Area'), without having to refresh the page. This is a basic scaffold with a bootstrap modal added.

I would also like to update the table contents with the new area. (After the modal is hidden.) I am using this code to do so.

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_area").on "ajax:success", (event, area, status, xhr) ->
    $('#new-area-modal').modal('hide')
    $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + area.area_name + '</td><td>' + area.area_number + '</td><td>' + area.area_description + '</td></tr>')
```

This works quite well. However, I can't figure out how to append the show/edit/destoy links to the table.

I've tried to insert `link_to 'Show', area`, but I have not had success.

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_area").on "ajax:success", (event, area, status, xhr) ->
    $('#new-area-modal').modal('hide')
    $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + area.area_name + '</td><td>' + area.area_number + '</td><td>' + area.area_description + '</td><td>' + link_to 'Show', area + '</td></tr>')
```

I'm new to rails, particularly when it comes to using Javascript + Rails combined. I'm not sure if this is actually possible, or if I'm just missing somthing small.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: The console doesn't seem like it is displaying anything different. However, when *link_to 'Show', area* is used, the table doesn't get updated at all.  
It just fails silently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ruby code inside the cofeescript:

**Using ERB:**

```
$ ()->
  $("form.new_area").on "ajax:success", (event, area, status, xhr) ->
    $('#new-area-modal').modal('hide')
    link_tag = "<%=j link_to('Show', area) %>"
    $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + area.area_name + '</td><td>' + area.area_number + '</td><td>' + area.area_description + '</td><td>' + link_tag + '</td></tr>')
```

**If using HAML:**

```
link_tag = "#{j link_to('Show', area)}"
```

The method `j` used here `<%=j link_to('Show', area) %>` is a shorthand for `escape_javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are editing the correct files. Rails can be complicated, especially when you first start because there are so many files that it generates. The file that you want to edit should be in app>views>area>index.html.erb

from there you want something that looks along the lins of

<%= link_to 'Show', product %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}